# the configuration section 'securityCrytographyConfiguration' can not be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: iis-7

when i create a new website in IIS 7.0, i get this error "the configuration section 'securityCrytographyConfiguration' can not be read because it is missing a section declaration". Please, help me.

Comment: Given the lack of mind-reading ability and absence of crystal balls, could you post your config file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you were aiming for [`SecurityCryptographyConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services3.security.configuration.securitycryptographyconfiguration.aspx), but that you've dropped the `p` in `Cryptography`.

Comment: sorry ,i mean 'SecurityCryptographyConfiguration',but i can't solve this problem.I created in Windows 7 platform via TeamViewer.